# Is there any way to use loop to change variable's strings from lowercase to uppercase?

Tags: javascript, loops

(Sorry for my bad English)
I'm new to JS and continuously doing some weird stuff to learn how JS works!
I'm currently wanting to change the array strings from lower case to uppercase and to do that, I'm doing something like this:

```
        let names = ['Shakir', 'smith', 'Anderson', 'Kyle', 'Ketty', 'jason'];
        
      
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    
    // This also doesn't work, i'm not using let (or any other variable keyword because names has already been defined: names[i] = to.UpperCase(names[i]); 
    
// Neither does this: let names[i] = to.UpperCase(names[i]);
    
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm mistaking?

Once again, this is my array:

```
let names = ['Shakir', 'smith', 'Anderson', 'Kyle', 'Ketty', 'jason'];
```

And I want to convert all the strings inside it from lower cases to uppercase like:

```
 let names = ['SHAKIR', 'SMITH', etc..]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can assign to the array entry in your loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Also be sure to get the method name right, I've corrected it above. And it's a *method* of the string, so you call it on the string rather than passing the string into it as an argument.

Another option is to create a new array with the modified entries in it, perhaps assigning it back to the same variable:

```
names = names.map(name => name.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I was doing toUpperCase.names instead of the opposite! Also, why we cant do "let names [i]" in the loop? I thought doing "let names [i]" would be much safer than to simply doing names[i]

Comment: @prettyversatile - `let` declares variables. Variables can't have `[` or `]` in their names. You could do `let newName = names[i].toUpperCase();`, but all that would do is store the upper-case name in a variable that will disappear at the end of that loop iteration (because I used `let` in the example; that's also true for `const`, but not `var`).

Answer (score 1):

The method is .toUpperCase() and you need to add the string before it (see docs: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_touppercase.asp)

So in your example, you would need to do:

```
let names = ['Shakir', 'smith', 'Anderson', 'Kyle', 'Ketty', 'jason']

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: Yes. I just realized that - Thank you!

Comment: Also, why we cant do "let names [i]" in the loop? I thought doing "let names [i]" would be much safer than to simply doing names[i]

Comment: You've already declared the variable 'names' as an array. 

You can’t redeclare a let within the same scope. 

In the loop, you're simply overwriting the value in the ‘names’ array with the uppercase text by using the i variable as the index.
 You can read more here on the let variable here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let